# useSelector not updating values, and not triggering useEffect but value can be read using store (redux)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, web, redux

I've been using Redux for quite some time now but for some reason my code just doesn't work:

```
import { store } from "../pages/_app";
....
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [state_sample, setSs]: any = useState(0); // - just use for triggering useEffect
  const audioCurrentTimeState: any = useSelector((state: RootState) => {
    state.AudioCurrentTimeState;
  });

  useEffect(() => { // - I am trying to trigger this useEffect but it doesn't work
    console.log(audioCurrentTimeState); // - doesn't work (?)
    console.log(store.getState().AudioCurrentTimeState); // - works
  }, [audioCurrentTimeState, state_sample]);

  return (
    <div className={style.waveform_component_root}>
      <p
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("clicked!");
          setSs(Math.random()); // - just use for triggering useEffect
          dispatch({
            type: "AudioCurrentTimeReducer/SET",
            value: Math.random(),
          });
        }}
      >
        click me
      </p>
   </div>)
```

Here is the reducer of `audioCurrentTimeState` :

```
export const AudioCurrentTimeReducer = (value = 0, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "AudioCurrentTimeReducer/SET":
      return action.value;
    default:
      return value;
  }
};
```

Here is `rootState` :

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import {
  AudioCurrentTimeReducer,
} from "./reducers/reducers";

const rootReducers = combineReducers({
  AudioCurrentTimeState: AudioCurrentTimeReducer,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducers>;

export default rootReducers;
```

And I setup by redux like this :

```
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import rootReducers from "../scripts/redux/rootReducer";

export const store = createStore(rootReducers);

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

I've never encountered this issue before, and I can't seem to find any references if there are any changes. But as you can see from above I can only get the value of `AudioCurrentTimeState` if I call it by `store.getState().AudioCurrentTimeState` not by `useSelector` and I need to trigger the useEffect for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return the value in the `useSelector`

correct:

```js
  const audioCurrentTimeState: any = useSelector((state: RootState) => {
    RETURN state.AudioCurrentTimeState;
  });

// OR short
  const audioCurrentTimeState: any = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.AudioCurrentTimeState);
```

was:

```js
  const audioCurrentTimeState: any = useSelector((state: RootState) => {
    state.AudioCurrentTimeState;
  });
```